# Use a Shared Template to create an Email in a child Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

We have a template created in the Parent Business Unit. We have shared the Template with Edit permission to the child Business Unit. When we go into the child Business Unit, I see the template under Shared With Us. When I create an Email I am not able to see or use the Template under Saved.

How do I create an Email with the Shared Template?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I was missing a step. When you create the Email you have to click the Filters/Folders button to select the Shared With Us directory. Then you will see and be able to use the Shared Template.